# Managing kernel driver code variations for similar devices in Git

Tags: c, git, linux-kernel

I'm working on a linux kernel device driver that handles several nearly identical devices with just a few value definition differences. Right now I just have an include that defines these values which gets modified to match the target device when I build a kernel. The values for each device will never change, so it seems inefficient to be constantly changing the file. I've included the driver source as a Git submodule and thought about creating separate branches for each device but since the driver is still in active development, I would be constantly merging changes from the master to the config branches. I'm pretty new to C/driver/Git development so maybe there's something totally obvious that I'm missing. Is there a better way to manage multiple stable config variations to changing C code being stored in a Git repo?

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need to compile differently depending on the device? Or could you package your different device details into structs, compile everything together, then let your driver select the appropriate struct to use at runtime when it identifies what device it's controlling?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way for the device to communicate which variation it is. The devices are basically the same but with variations of subcomponents so some limits and data handling factors need to be adjusted. It's not the best setup, but it's what I have to work with.

Comment: Presumably this is on ARM, in which case you could specify the values in the device tree.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best method to manage this is called [conditional compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_compilation), and implementing it in your case will involve two steps:

First, make sure your device-specific details are completely abstracted from your actual driver implementation and in separate files. It sounds like you already have this, because you said you are just changinge a `#include` statement to compile for different devices. Great!

Second, add a `#include` to your driver for every header file, but separate them with [preprocessor conditional expressions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.2/cpp_4.html). Something like this:

```
#ifdef USING_FIRST_DEVICE
#include "first_device_details.h"

#elif defined(USING_SECOND_DEVICE)
#include "second_device_details.h"

#else
#include "some_default_device_details.h"

#endif
```

Now all you have to do to compile for different devices is tell your compiler to consider one of the macros to be "defined". I'm no makefile or kernel build system expert, so you'll have to figure out how to actually wedge this macro definition into your makefile. The GCC compilers use the -D flag for it. For example, if you weren't building a kernel module, you could call the compiler like this:

> gcc -D USING_SECOND_DEVICE mydriver.c -o outfile

This would compile mydriver.c, and if mydriver.c had the previous code snippet at the top of it, it would try to include "second_device_details.h" without the other two header files.

I think this approach will suite you for a few reasons:

1. Everything can be on one git branch without file conflicts.
2. You can compile for your different devices without changing any of your files.
3. If you abstract the device details from everything else well enough, changes in your mainline code should apply across all your devices without any copying or branch merging.